# CloudFormation Select ImageId based on Instance Family

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to select an AMI dynamically based on the Instance Family.  The instance family being determined from the first few letters (before the period) from the InstanceType.

I would think that the following CloudFormation snippet would work. It uses `!Select` and `!Split` to find the first few characters of the InstanceType. The Instance Family should be passed as the third argument to FindInMap. However, it fails with the error:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template error: every Fn::FindInMap object requires three parameters, the map name, map key and the attribute for return value

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: my new server
Parameters:
  InstanceType:
    Description: Instance Type
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
     - t2.micro
     - t3a.small
     - t3a.medium
     - t4g.micro
     - t4g.small
     - t4g.medium

Mappings:
  AmiMap:
    us-east-1:
      ## AMD64 Instances
      t2:   ami-0f65ab0fd913bc7be
      t3a:  ami-0f65ab0fd913bc7be
      ## Graviton (ARM) Instances
      t4g:   ami-0cf2a935e8b19b29b

Resources:

  LaunchConfig:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      ...
      ImageId: !FindInMap
        - AmiMap
        - "us-east-1"
        - !Select [0, !Split [".", !Ref InstanceType ]]
```

Why isn't the `!Select ... !Split` line returning a string for `FindInMap` to recognize?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: It did work, but I came up with a more clear solution. Posting it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recognized by @Paolo and @Marcin, `!Select` can't be used inside a `!FindInMap`. The full instance type (ie: `t4g.small`) can't be used as keys inside the `Mappings` section either, since they contain non alpha-numeric characters.

I feel like this is a better solution, rather than trying to split the instance type (`t4g.small`) to find the Instance Family, it constructs the `InstanceType` from an `InstanceFamily` + `InstanceSize`. That way, we can use the `InstanceFamily` inside the Mappings.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: My Server
Parameters:

  InstanceFamily:
    Description: "Instance Family ie: t4g, t3a, m5)"
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - t2
      - t3
      - t3a
      - t4g

  InstanceSize:
    Description: "Instance Size (micro, small, medium, large)"
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - micro
      - small
      - medium
      - large

Mappings:
  AmiMap:
    ## Last Updated 2022-07-01
    us-east-1:
      ## AMD64 Instances. Ubuntu 22.04 us-east-1
      t2:   ami-0f65ab0fd913bc7be 
      t3:   ami-0f65ab0fd913bc7be
      t3a:  ami-0f65ab0fd913bc7be

      ## Graviton (ARM) Instances Ubuntu 22.04 us-east-1
      t4g:   ami-0cf2a935e8b19b29b

Resources:
  LaunchConfig:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
      BlockDeviceMappings:
         ...
      ImageId: !FindInMap
        - AmiMap
        - "us-east-1"
        - !Ref InstanceFamily
      InstanceType: !Join ['.', [!Ref InstanceFamily, !Ref InstanceSize]]
      InstanceMonitoring: false
      ...
```